# What is the JavaScript variable 'empty'

Tags: javascript, arrays

Doing Array.apply(null,[1]) gets me this [empty] but Array(null,[1,2]) gets me [1,2]
the array with 'empty' has a length of one but index zero is undefined.

`Array.apply(null,[1]).length`
  1
`Array.apply(null,[1])[0]`
  undefined
`Array.apply(null,[1])`
  [empty]

```js
console.log(Array.apply([1]));
console.log(Array.apply([1]).length);
```

Comment: Also, `Array.apply` calls `Function#apply` since `Array` is a (constructor) function, and supplies `[1]` as the `this` value with 0 arguments when calling `Array`.

Comment: But why is the empty item there? I put in a vaild value and `Array.apply([1,2])` seems to work just fine

Comment: @Li357 I understand what apply does it was just the context I used it in. also wouldn't the `1` be an argument?

Comment: `Array.apply([1]).length` evaluates to 0, not 1.

Comment: @TheIntellectual No, the first argument to `apply` is the context.

Comment: I don't get the same result as you. Try `Array.apply(null, [1,2])` or `Array.apply(null, [1])`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I forgot the null for argument one my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting two different results is that in the first case of doing:

```
Array.apply(null,[4])
```

You are simply invoking the JavaScript Array constructor with a list of one argument. This single argument to the constructor is used to create an array of size `n` where `n` is the number you have in the list. It creates this list without anything in it.

For me in a node REPL, this is the result of the above:

```
> Array.apply(null, [4])
[ <4 empty items> ]
```

In the second case where you did:

```
Array.apply(null, [1, 2])
```

This is another constructor overload used to specify the contents of the array. So in this case, you are telling the array constructor to create an array containing the elements `1`, `2`.

```
> Array.apply(null, [1, 2])
[ 1, 2 ]
```

See the [MDN documentation for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters).

Comment: So the number is to tell it to make an array that has no values but has length of 1?

Comment: @TheIntellectual Yes. the number is used to tell the constructor how big to make the array; aka the length.

Comment: so this would get me an array with all values being `4`? `Array(4).map(item => 4)`

Comment: @TheIntellectual try `Array(4).fill(4)`. See this interesting [article](https://itnext.io/heres-why-mapping-a-constructed-array-doesn-t-work-in-javascript-f1195138615a) explaining why `map` didn't work

Comment: `Array(4).fill(0).map(item => Math.floor(Math.random()*10))` works but `Array(4).map(item => Math.floor(Math.random()*10))` doesn't

Comment: @TheIntellectual See the link I have in my previous comment

Comment: `var x = Array(4); x[1] = 0; x.map(item => 1);` returns `[empty,1,empty,empty,empty]` so I guess javascript skips empty array slots.

Comment: @TheIntellectual it doesn't skip them; they simply don't exist. `empty` might as well mean `void` or `nonexistent`

Comment: still I think it's weird I have to assign them values when using map because what if there is one in the array that you didn't know about.

Comment: @TheIntellectual You can always use `Array.length` as a source of truth

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like `empty` variable in Javascript, they are empty slots. You are calling `Array([1,2])` instead `Array.apply([1,2])`.
Both `Array.apply([1])` and `Array.apply([1,2])` will give you same result which will be `[]`.

But when you call `Array.apply(this,[1])` it will result in `[empty]` because internally it is equal to `Array(1)`. And when you call `Array.apply(this,[1,2])` it is equal to `Array(1,2)` which will be `[1,2]`. When only one number passed to Array constructor it returns an array of empty slots with its length property set to that number.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters)

Comment: I forgot the null for the "this" but `Array.apply(null,[1])` gets me [empty]

Comment: FYI, empty is just a thing the browser outputs for a more friendly output. It usually means an array with length but no contents.

Comment: @Li357 but why is there no content?

Comment: @TheIntellectual See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Parameters). It states that if there is only one argument it's treated as the array length with no content (empty slots)